# Position, Velocity and Time

Tags: ros, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a standard ROS message that can represent an object's x, y position along with its velocity at each position and time passed at the position?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273309/position,-velocity-and-time/) by [Divya Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32290/divya-thomas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-10-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
It would be good if you could provide a little more details. Are you looking for something that can report *current state*, or something that is used to encode *desired state*?

**Comment by [Divya Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/32290/divya-thomas/) on 2017-10-18**:
This is for desired state.  I'm trying to output points along a trajectory where each point represents x, y, desired velocity at that point, and the time to get to the point.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-18**:
To encode desired state, a *trajectory* would seem to be the logical choice. That would be what @tfoote suggested. However, perhaps a [nav_msgs/Path](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) would be better suited than the `trajectory_msgs` he links to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That sounds a lot like a Trajectory specifically the MultiDOFJointTrajectory http://wiki.ros.org/trajectory_msgs

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2017-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0